# MySQL: Showing only orders that have a balance due when there are multiple bill tables for each order (and multiple payments)

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join

My goal is to get a (relatively efficient) MySQL view that shows all orders that still have an outstanding balance--showing the invoice amount, the sum of all storage fees, total amount paid, and total due for each order. The two "bills" are the original invoice amount from the orders table and then the sum of all storage amounts (fees) from the storage table.

There is the invoice amount in the orders table, all the payments for particular orders in the payments table and all the extra storage fees for particular orders in the storage table (the payment and storage tables are related to the orders table on order_id field).

Below is my schema with example data (and here is the [SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8e6f3) if that is helpful):

```
CREATE TABLE orders
(
order_id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
invoice decimal(10,2),
PRIMARY KEY (order_id)
);


CREATE TABLE payments
(
payments_id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
order_id int,
amount decimal(10,2),
PRIMARY KEY (payments_id)
);

CREATE TABLE storage
(
storage_id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
order_id int,
amount decimal(10,2),
PRIMARY KEY (storage_id)
);


INSERT INTO orders (invoice)
VALUES ('250'), (NULL), ('150'), ('175.00'), ('175.00'), (NULL);

INSERT INTO payments (order_id, amount)
VALUES ('1', '50'), ('3', '50'), ('1', '100'), ('1', '150'), ('4', '100'), ('4', '25'), ('3', '50');

INSERT INTO storage (order_id, amount)
VALUES ('1', '50'), ('4', '25');
```

The following query works but because I repeat so much and it looks like a total of 5 subqueries, I am guessing this is not an efficient way to get this to work:

```
CREATE VIEW accounts_receivable AS
SELECT
orders.order_id AS orderid,
orders.invoice,
(SELECT sum(amount) from storage WHERE storage.order_id = orders.order_id) AS storagebill,
coalesce(sum(payments.amount), 0) AS paid,
coalesce(orders.invoice, 0) + (SELECT coalesce(SUM(storage.amount), 0) FROM storage WHERE storage.order_id = orders.order_id) - (SELECT coalesce(sum(payments.amount), 0) FROM payments WHERE orders.order_id = payments.order_id) AS due
FROM orders
LEFT JOIN payments on payments.order_id = orders.order_id
WHERE
(coalesce(orders.invoice, 0) + (SELECT coalesce(SUM(storage.amount), 0) FROM storage WHERE storage.order_id = orders.order_id) - (SELECT coalesce(sum(payments.amount), 0) FROM payments WHERE orders.order_id = payments.order_id)) > 0
GROUP BY orders.order_id
```

Is there any way to get this data in a more efficient way? I am guessing there are some different ways of joining the data here but I have experimented (and searched for the answer) to no avail. I am relatively new to SQL.

Comment: I think  you omitted an comparison operator on you last where clause.

Comment: If there are 'multiple bills' for each order - shouldn't there be a bills table, or is that what the storage fee is?  The more I read this the more I think there's a better way to work the schema - but maybe I'm wrong

Comment: @MageeWorld Yes, the storage table is the other "bill" table. I tried to summarize the title as well as I could but maybe it was not quite accurate. But the idea is that they have to pay  both the invoice and any storage fees they accumulate over time and that should all be accounted for in amount paid and amount due (and in the WHERE clause as well). They are my tables so I could change the tables if that would make more sense.

Comment: @lrb Yes you are right about the WHERE clause needing an operator "> 0". Somehow that did not make it in when I simplified the query but I have changed it now. Thank you!

Comment: Ideally, your design should yield a simple tally of line item amounts joined by an order or invoice with corresponding payment amounts in such a way that positive summation of amount-payment is money not yet collected and negative indicates money paid out(refunded). How can order_id 6 have no payments, invoice amount or storage? Is it a placeholder for a future purchase? If so then that could be bad.

Comment: @lrb Indeed it is possible for order_id 6 to have no payments, invoice amount, or storage fees because it is something like: user puts the order in the system and maybe gives customer an estimate but the invoice amount is not inputted until after the work has been done (perhaps several days later). After that payment begins.

Comment: Ah, I see. It makes sense then.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry about the re-format. I am questioning the storage table and why the invoice is not broken out into smaller parts. However, I do not know the details and maybe that is a good thing :) Here is a working query that gives you similar results with a little more readability.

```
SELECT
    * 
FROM
(
    SELECT 
        orderid,
        invoice,
        storage,
        totaldue=invoice+storage,
        totalpaid=paid,
        amountdue=(invoice+storage)-paid
    FROM
    (
            SELECT
                orderid=orders.order_id,
                invoice=orders.invoice,
                storage=
                (
                    SELECT SUM(amount) FROM storage where order_id=orders.order_id
                ),
                paid=SUM(payments.amount)   
            FROM
                orders
                LEFT OUTER JOIN payments on payments.order_id=orders.order_id                       
            GROUP BY
                orders.order_id,orders.invoice
    )AS DETAIL  
)AS SUMMARY
WHERE
    SUMMARY.amountdue>0
```

Comment: Unfortunately, because I have to make a MySQL VIEW out of it, MySQL won't let me put a subquery in "FROM" so I don't think I can use the solution above. Also, to address what you said: You make a good point about the questionableness of the schema. Unfortunately there are some other software constraints that make it problematic to have one table for all "bills" or even to have a separate invoice table along with a separate storage table. Having said that, I really appreciate all your help!